# VNC not working when Desktop Sleep

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access, remote-login

I need to use VNC client on an Ubuntu Desktop. When the machine is not sleep, I do VNC. But it is sleep, and I try to connect with VNC, it will say the machine is not up. Is there a method that allow me to wake up the machine via VNC or any equivalent software?

Thanks